# Independent strip themes for ggplot2 facet_wrap using more than one variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Is it possible to have independent strip themes for each variable used in ggplot2 `facet_wrap`?

Take this chunk of code as an example:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
   geom_point() +
   facet_wrap(c("cyl", "drv"), labeller = "label_both")
plot(p1)
```

[image: Plot output]

I would want to have upper strip ('cyl') with a different theme - say, in bold. Additionally, I might want to make 'drv' italic and with a different font type and size. How could I do that?

I was thinking something in the lines of:

```
 p1 <- p1 + theme(strip.text.variable1 = element_text(face = 'bold'),
                  strip.text.variable2 = element_text(face = 'italic', size = 8)
                  )
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything like this in the docs or previous questions.

Cheers

*Edit: I made the question a bit more general to be of further help to the community.*

Comment: [How to use different font sizes in ggplot facet wrap labels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334486/how-to-use-different-font-sizes-in-ggplot-facet-wrap-labels) seems relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Ostensibly you should be able to make a new function based on `label_both` to return bold labels, but so far my attempts have ended with the dreaded `Error in variable[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`.

An alternative to this is to build a function to make the label you want.  This is much like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32806100/2461552).  In this function you add the prefix to the values of the variable and make them bold.

```
make_labels = function(string, prefix = "cyl: ") {
    x = paste0(prefix, as.character(string))
    do.call(expression, lapply(x, function(y) bquote(bold(.(y)))))
}
```

Now use this function within `as_labeller` for the "cyl" variable in `facet_wrap`.  You want to change the default labeller within `as_labeller` to `label_parsed` so the expression is parsed correctly.  Use `label_both` for the other variable.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(c("cyl", "drv"), 
               labeller = labeller(cyl = as_labeller(make_labels, default = label_parsed), 
                                   drv = label_both))
```

[image]

Comment: That's definitely one way out, thanks. However, I'm stuck with using the `label_both` parameter for "cyl" in order to anchor the `prefix = "cyl: "` call. It would also be interesting to use this function free of constraints (e.g. with `label_value`, instead).

Comment: I agree that it would be nice to not hard-code the labeller to your particular variable (although you don't have to use `"cyl: "`, use whatever your variable name is instead).  I don't quite follow your second sentence, as the function I wrote is specifically meant to be used with `label_parsed` in order use `bold`.

Comment: Yes, I meant `"cyl: "` only as an example (in my case is `"method: "`). Sorry if I wasn't clear about the second sentence. What I meant to say is that this solution only works if we explicitly put the name of the variable in the function (and it gets included in the strip itself) - it would be good for it to work if I didn't want "cyl: 4", "cyl: 5", "cyl 6", "cyl: 8" in the strip text, just "4", "5", "6", and "8".

Comment: Make a labeling function without the `prefix` argument to have bold labels of the values.  The main difference would be that `x = paste0(...)` would change to `x = as.character(string)`.